# Solr instance accessible from browser but not from terminal

Tags: solr

I'm working on creating a search engine using Python + Solr. I went through the demo tutorials given here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/solr-tutorial.html#exercise-1 . I am able to create the solr instance as well as create a collection and add documents to it and perform search. I'm able to open the link http://192.168.0.202:8983/solr/ on my browser. The same is not opening from the terminal. Would anyone here have an idea how to fix this ?

Thanks,
Nilesh.

Comment: So what are you trying to do when you say "opening from the terminal"?

Comment: Basically ping http://192.168.0.202:8983/solr

Comment: That's not how ping works. `ping` sends an ICMP packet to a server, not an HTTP url. If you're trying to ping a server, `ping 192.168.0.202` would be the way to do that, assuming that the server (and your network between the server and your computer) allows ICMP packets and responds to ping requests.